# Can I ban players from my party?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I've encountered some toxic players whose behavior have not crossed the line into anything GM-actionable, but quickly kill any assembled raiding parties I form.  If I blacklist them, are they still able to join my parties in the Party Finder?

If so, is there another way I can prevent specific individuals from joining my Party Finder groups?

Finally, does Duty Finder respect the blacklist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what the accepted answer says, as it has been the case for a while (at the time of posting this):

- If you kick someone from a party, they can't rejoin the party ([link](https://forum.square-enix.com/ffxiv/threads/325246-Can-we-get-an-Allow-Re-entry-option-for-kicking-from-Cross-World-Parties) for a post asking to allow re-entry)
- If you have blacklisted someone or someone has blacklisted you, you can't join the party in the party finder if they're the leader (and vice-versa), as the entry will be greyed out: [exemple here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffxiv/comments/2lfgmf/party_finder_entry_greyed_out/)

Comment: The Duty Finder part is still true though.  Blacklist doesn't have any impact on Duty Finder, only Party Finder (and there only for the leader - e.g. two people who have put each other on their blacklists can join a party hosted by a third person).

Answer (score 0):

> Can I ban players from my party?

No.

> I've encountered some toxic players whose behavior have not crossed the line
>   into anything GM-actionable, but quickly kill any assembled raiding parties I
>   form. If I blacklist them, are they still able to join my parties in the Party
>   Finder?

Yes.

> If so, is there another way I can prevent specific individuals from joining my
>   Party Finder groups?

Not that I'm aware of, but as long as you haven't entered the instance yet, you can remove them from the party with `/kick Player Name` or by right clicking them in the party list. There's nothing to stop them from rejoining your party immediately, though.

> Finally, does Duty Finder respect the blacklist?

It doesn't.